# mysql unique index with compound index

Tags: mysql, indexing, unique-constraint

I have one table in mysql as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE `demo_tbl` (
    `id`        MEDIUMINT(8) NOT NULL,
    `uniquefld` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    `field1`    VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `ux_uniquefld` (`uniquefld` ASC),
    INDEX `ix_uniquefld_field1` (`uniquefld` ASC, `field1` ASC)
);
```

Here I have created 2 indexes, one unique index for `uniquefld` field and another is for 2 fields `uniquefld` & `field1`.

Is there any way to create single index instead of two with uniqueness for `uniquefld`?

Comment: `CONSTRAINT uc_uniquefld UNIQUE (uniquefld)` Go for `constraint`

Comment: @NagendraNigade, Is is supported by mysql?

Answer (score 0):

why do you need to index ix_uniquefld_field1? since uniquefld is unique, any query on uniquefld+field1 can do just fine by accessing the index on ux_uniquefld.

Comment: hi @gilg, because field1 has used in order by as well as select clause, and this table has about 2 million records, my select query is performing slow and I want optimize it.

Comment: can you paste the query?

Comment: As mention by gilg , paste your query which will help us to find where its taking time

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE demo_tbl (
    id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    uniquefld VARCHAR(20) CONSTRAINT uid_uniquefld UNIQUE,
    field1    VARCHAR(20),
);
CREATE INDEX idx_field1 ON demo_tbl (field1);
```

This will Work much effectively.